# Can I post a survey for my masters thesis on stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I am working on my masters thesis and I am trying to reach as many software developers as possible with a survey concerning testing for software vulnerabilities. Is it acceptable to post such a survey on stackexchange? If so which stackexchange site would be the best place to post it?

Comment: Why do you assume Stack Exchange is where all the software developers are? They've all moved to Xing

Answer (score 12):

No, you cannot post such a survey on Stack Exchange sites.

Posts on Stack Exchange sites are either questions or answers, within the scope defined for the site they are posted on. Questions are expected to get answers that can be subjectively voted on - for that reason (and others), polls of any kind are not generally allowed (including recommendations, shopping requests and lists).

A survey certainly falls into the poll-like questions.

Comment: By "shopping requests" do you mean things like "Where can I buy ___"?

Comment: Also those. We use it as a blanket term for recommendation requests (which book/library/brand/___ should I get).