# Let's limit MSE participation to people who have accounts on other sites

Tags: feature-request, meta, new-users, sign-up

I'm sure we've all seen questions asked on MSE by new users, who think that this is a place to ask questions about parenting (as one did just tonight, but was deleted *very* quickly) or programming or any other topic under the sun. I think (though I have no evidence) that this happens because people hear about "[stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/)" being a good place for getting answers to questions (which it is), but don't realize that we have a *network* of sites. Meta is probably the site that comes closest to being a central site of Stack Exchange, so they'll post their "blatantly off-topic" questions here.

**I think one way to help fix this is to block users that don't have accounts on other sites from asking questions here.** In any event, they shouldn't have anything to ask about (bugs, site policy, etc.) if they don't use the network at all.

Comment: Meh, there's an extremely high chance that they'd just post somewhere else on the network. At least here there's a good volume of users prepared to deal with it.

Comment: Related (I think): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177485/266359

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I agree it would help solve programming and other wildly off-topic questions, but it would be at the expense of at least several legimate uses:

- Site recommendations and asking if particular questions are suitable anyhwere on the Stack Exchange network.
- Companies seeking information on subjects such as advertisting and Careers 2.0.

While the person who posted [Can I post a survey for my masters thesis on stack exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247230/can-i-post-a-survey-for-my-masters-thesis-on-stack-exchange) does have an account elsewhere despite the negative reception the question received it's still better than having them post their survey on 100+ SE sites without asking beforehand.

Comment: Your first bullet point makes sense to me, but wouldn't the second be accomplished much faster/more officially by contacting SE directly by email?

Comment: I guess in most cases and especially for pricing, although I've seen a few posts about general policy that could be handy to know (for them and others) upfront before making official contact.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Have a silver badge ;-)