# Require having a few reputation on at least one other site before posting to MSE

Tags: feature-request, meta, new-users, privileges

We get quite a few questions every day from users who somehow get lost and ask questions that are completely off-topic here, mainly users who seem to think they are on Stack Overflow.

I have been thinking about this a bit lately, and think I might have some sort of a solution: **what if users needed to have maybe 10 reputation on another Stack Exchange site to participate in Main Meta?**

I think this seems like a good solution. It would make it impossible for lost users to have their first posts be here. From what I've seen, the vast majority of users who post blatantly off-topic questions have no other accounts or no reputation on their other accounts.

Comment: Alternatively, we could just require that they have to have posted a question or answer on another site if we want a lower threshold.

Comment: Also, may I ask why I got a downvote (I know I do this every time I get a downvote, just what's bad about the question)?

Comment: I'd prefer we figure out the path people are using, and fix that.  There's obviously some confusion inherent in people asking questions here, and almost every time, they just joined this site, and another one, that day.  So somewhere along the line, there's a link to here that's causing this.

Comment: Related: [Let's limit MSE participation to people who have accounts on other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247236/295232)

Comment: FWIW I've seen lost souls on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/23377) and Hardware Recommendations too.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think part of the problem may be that on every question page, there's a "Featured on Meta" box which shows a current 'hot' item _here_. Right under it, however, there's "Hot Meta Posts", which shows some current 'hot' postings _on the stack's own meta_. To someone who isn't familiar with the organization of StackExchange, this is _going_ to be confusing. Perhaps this needs to be looked at, and perhaps the boxes retitled?

Comment: Why is it a problem that needs a solution?

Comment: I edited this site anonymously without an account for a couple of years. So I'm opposed to any request that restricts the abilities of new users to contribute.

Comment: Slightly related: Meta SE had a period where it [needed **2** reputation on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278592/241919) to post.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278683/statistics-regarding-users-who-recently-flooded-mse-with-blatantly-off-topic-deb?noredirect=1#comment902510_278683.

Answer (score 21):

The glut of misplaced questions appearing here is a somewhat recent spike (self-inflicted, I believe). If passers-by are easily confused about where they are, that is on *us* — we should fix that… but ***not*** by blocking well-meaning users needing help.

The problem is that the support channels and service channels look virtually identical; navigation between them is largely obscured. If there is merit in preserving this simplified mono-design, **there should at least be an interstitial pop-up** to verify what they would like to do.

> <kbd>Ask a programming question</kbd>      <kbd>I need help with Stack Exchange</kbd>

But meta is essentially the "customer support" channel for the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange network, so all sorts of inquiries, customer service matters, and technical support issues come through here. It would be untenable for *any* service to say that someone needs to be an *active* customer before having a question or talking to us at all — **so that is a non-starter**… in my opinion.

Comment: Tim says there's supposed to be an interstitial.  But there's been no response as to what that looks like, when I asked in January.  Can you confirm there is one, and if so, let us see what it looks like?

Comment: @fbueckert I don't see anything like that in private/incognito mode. Doesn't mean it's not there somewhere, but last time I suggested it, I was told we wouldn't be doing that (maybe that's changed; don't know).

Comment: Okay, that's new.  Then [Tim's idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317599/193762) needs an update as to how we're supposed to solve this.  Throwing something in the way would be very appreciated to help stem what seems like an awful lot of confused askers here.

Comment: I saw this recently, when proposing the Ask Question wizard for Meta @fbueckert. will look and make a screenshot. (Edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1Tsx.png)

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard That's the interstitial?  It just looks like the How to Ask page.  At least the proceed button is tiny, so askers have to hunt for it.

Comment: Yeah, I would have expected separate buttons asking  what they would like to do —  `ask a programming question` or  `I need help with Stack Exchange`... for example

Comment: @RobertCartaino There is a discussion regarding [potentially enabling the wizard here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327257/the-question-wizard-might-be-useful-for-meta-stack-exchange-too-should-we-give) and it does put forth the idea of a separate button for "programming" questions.

Answer (score 8):

This would prevent a handful of cases where a Meta post might be warranted. Some examples:

- If a user is suspended on Example Stack Exchange, they can't ask a question about it on Example Meta since they're suspended there as well. Instead, they can post on Meta Stack Exchange.
- If a user wants to post something 'anonymously' (i.e. start a potentially controversial discussion, or post an answer they don't want to be associated with their main account), they'd have to gain reputation on another site first.

On the other hand, it just takes [two clicks](https://stackapps.com/q/8122/34061) to deal with blatantly off-topic questions. (Disclaimer: I wrote that script.)

Comment: Questions regarding the first bullet point will probably be closed as off-topic/applicable to one site only (or duplicate if applicable).

Comment: They're often duplicates, but off-topic would be ... confusing. It's not even possible to migrate the question in that case, not even by moderators.

Comment: nah, from what I have seen, posts about suspensions on one site are almost always closed as "applicable only to one site" and the users are redirected to the mod message/contact SE team link. There are certainly exceptions, but this is my recent experience.

Answer (score 8):

Nope nope nope.

There are many reasons not to, I'm sure I'm missing some, but here are the first two that come to mind:

- having the ability to post at 1 rep allows you to post anonymously if needed. Sure, you could make a dummy account elsewhere, but that's not optimal and against the point
- you could very well ask a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) at 1 rep, even if you have no activity elsewhere (yet). That sounds a bit daydreaming, given that (indeed) a lot of new users are lost souls, but still - you do not want to prevent someone from getting useful direction *especially* if it helps de-cluttering other sites.

Note that, as a side point, there's a 5-rep limit for per-site metas; and even then you're allowed to ask questions there but only about your own posts.