# Is inviting for a survey SPAM?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110781/how-does-everyone-use-communication-apis) popped up, and got for sure quickly downvoted and delete-voted in 7 minutes. Anyway: it reads:

> I am undertaking a research study on the use of communication API tools and am looking for help. It will take no more than 2 minutes of your time. We are offering a prize for respondents. ... link ... some more details

As the author is disclosing his identity - am I correct in *not* flagging this as SPAM?

Edit: the *core* of my question is if flagging as *spam* is appropriate - as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/1531124) for example clearly states that spam is about *commercial advertisement*. The only reference to "survey == spam?" is an answer that says "flagged it as spam" - without giving **any** further arguments why that is appropriate.

Given the severe consequences of flagging as spam - I think a more canonical (argument based) answer is needed.

Comment: I accepted the duplicates, but now I am not so sure any more. Nothing in the duplicated questions gives clear arguments for either "it is SPAM" or "no it is NOT".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are research survey questions expected to be handled with close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278250/are-research-survey-questions-expected-to-be-handled-with-close-votes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is *definitely* off-topic on Stack Overflow. Disclosing the OP's relationship with the site is a precondition for including promotional links to external sites in *on-topic* posts, but posting a question, answer, or comment merely to promote your own site (or project, service, interest, religion, point of view, scientific theory, etc) is just plain .... spam.

Comment: Tangentially, "spam" is not an acronym, so there are no reasons to spell it in upper case.

Comment: According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/1531124) SPAM is about **commercial** advertisement. And keep in mind: flagging as SPAM ( I like it uppercase ;-) can have **severe** consequences for the person being flagged. This is a pretty powerful instrument, so it should be used carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I added a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260638/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-spam-for-stack-overflow/260641#comment512176_260641) suggesting they rethink the phrasing there.