# Why are there links to answers in the related questions list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, related-questions

On two three of the four newest Meta questions, there are posts in the "related" section without a title:

[image]

I was curious to see what that was, and the link was a link to an answer. Clicking the link took me to the answer, and the score in the link was the score of the answer, not of the question (in the example above, the answer had score 8 and the question had score 3).

What's also strange is that although it was a link to an answer, it had a question URL (in the example above https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300633).

I saw this happen just recently on several questions on both Meta Stack Exchange and Super User, and I have never seen this happen before. I'm quite sure this is a bug.

Comment: [cross-site dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356565/559745)

Comment: It becomes much worse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUonv.png (that's a link to some help center page on Russian.SE site)

Comment: There's also another issue which is probably related. Lots of questions don't have any Related questions at all. That is, the section doesn't exist at all. This seems to be a network-wide issue, and on new questions only. (Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300901/some-related-questions-blank)

Comment: @Dan yup, that's a total mess. Guess it's time for email to the team, as Tim suggested. :)

Comment: Interestingly this question is also affected. Perfectly meta.

Comment: We are aware of the issue, have a handle on the cause and are working on a fix. Hope to have it fixed in the next couple of hours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A recent refactor of how we do Elastic searches for related questions was referencing the wrong site (using `Current.Site` rather than a site passed to the operation) during the refresh process for a question. This led to seemingly random post identifiers being used for the related questions. When we came to render the URL it went one of a few ways:

- It couldn't find the question and so ignored it
- The `PostId` was actually that of an answer and so it didn't have a title
- The `PostId` was that of another type of post used for things like help posts (which are localized)

Eurgh. We've fixed it, purged caches and all is now well.

Thanks for the heads up <3